# will this.myObj = myObj store a reference or a copy/snapshot?

Tags: javascript, json, reference, duplicates

If myObj is a javascript object, will

```
this.myObj = myObj
```

create a copy/snapshot of what that object looks like at the moment, or will it store a reference to the actual object?

I am having trouble with what seems to be double sets of the same object, which is why I am starting to wonder if I am in fact maintaining copies when I don't want to...

Comment: Should be pretty easy to test -> http://jsfiddle.net/6cBKp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reference, for sure:

```
var foo = function () {};
var foo_instance = new foo();
var bar = {
    foo: foo_instance
};
console.log(foo_instance === bar.foo);    // true
```

If you want to clone the object, you have two alternatives:

**jQuery:**

```
var foo = function () {};
var foo_instance = new foo();

var foo_instance_clone = new foo();
$.extend(foo_instance_clone, foo_instance);
```

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
var foo = function () {};
var foo_instance = new foo();

var foo_instance_clone = new foo();
for (var key in foo_instance) {
    if (foo_instance.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        foo_instance_clone[key] = foo_instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a reference to the object. There is one object with two ways of "addressing" it.

```
function Cls(obj) {
  this.myObj = obj;
}

var foo = { bar : 1 }
var x = new Cls(foo);

foo.bar = 2;
console.log(x.myObj) // { bar : 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are just assigning a reference to an object. After all, you're only dealing with *references* in ECMAscript. There is no such thing like "the actual object" with that you can deal in memory, or clone it. Well you can clone it, but that would just create another object on the HEAP where you get a *reference* to.

Think of it like so...

```
var newObj = { };
```

What happens now is, that new object is formed/created somewhere on the HEAP and you have a reference to that in your `newObj` variable. When we go like

```
newObj.foo = newObj
```

we are just referencing to the same object, somewhere on the HEAP. No magic at all.